# How to run java Selenium on bash?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a feeling that the reason this isn't working is because I am importing selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to fix this problem.

Bash command:

```
java -cp "byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar:commons-exec-1.3.jar:guava-25.0-jre.jar:okhttp-3.11.0.jar:okio-1.14.0.jar:selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar:client-combined-3.141.59.jar:client-combined-3.141.59.jar" launchBrowser.java
```

Error thrown in terminal:

```
launchBrowser.java:3: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
                          
launchBrowser.java:4: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
                          
launchBrowser.java:5: error: package org.openqa.selenium.chrome does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
                                 
launchBrowser.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
  symbol:   class WebDriver
  location: class launchBrowser
launchBrowser.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                               
  symbol:   class ChromeDriver
  location: class launchBrowser
launchBrowser.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("@gmail.com");
                           
  symbol:   variable By
  location: class launchBrowser
launchBrowser.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        driver.findElement(By.className("dwads")).click();
                           
  symbol:   variable By
  location: class launchBrowser
7 errors
error: compilation failed
```

My code:

```java
package selenium.webdriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class launchBrowser {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/chromedriver_main/");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.className("VfPpkd-RLmnJb")).click();
        String at = driver.getTitle();
        String et = "gmail";
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will you also provide a simple code example for `launchBrowser.java` so anyone that wants to can try to run it?

Comment: Do these help: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922681/differences-between-java-cp-and-java-jar & https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/web/selenium/create-runnable-jar-from-selenium-script-using-eclipse.html

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work (When I use -jar instead of -cp)

Comment: Alright, I added my code

Comment: you should either import the client or the standalone server... not both.  The server version is used if you are running a grid on that machine.

Comment: Which do you recommend me using? I'm just learning the basics.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. It is missing all the imports and own package name.

Comment: Alright, I fixed it.