# How do I run a JAR while including another JAR as class path?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have two different JAR files, dependent.jar and independent.jar

dependent.jar gives a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when run, and requires classes from independent.jar to execute successfully. However, I cannot figure out a way to include independent.jar in the class path of dependent.jar

I tried using the command
`java -cp independent.jar -jar dependent.jar` 
However, the `-cp` option is ignored when used with `-jar` option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between "java -cp" and "java -jar"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922681/differences-between-java-cp-and-java-jar)

Comment: Does your `dependent.jar` have a manifest with a `Class-Path` entry?